# Python 3.5 multiprocessing pool and queue don't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I encounter a multiprocessing problem. The code is included below. The code can execute as expected, but when uncommenting `self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue()`, this program will exit immediately and it seems that the subprocess can't be started successfully.

I don't know what happened. Could someone help me out? Many Thanks!

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
        #self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def subprocess(self):
        for i in range(10):
            print("Running")
            time.sleep(1)
        print("Subprocess Completed")

    def start(self):
        self.pool.apply_async(func=self.subprocess)
        print("Subprocess has been started")
        self.pool.close()
        self.pool.join()

    def __getstate__(self):
        self_dict = self.__dict__.copy()
        del self_dict['pool']
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    test.start()
```

Comment: Any `traceback`, if so add it to your Question.

Comment: @stovfl Sorry, I can't see any traceback information in Pycharm console. If uncommenting that line, this program will complete immediately without waiting for its subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your Issue and also no `Traceback` raised up.
This should raise the following error, don't know why not:

> **RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance**

Replace your line of code with:

```
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    self.queue = m.Queue()
```

Why does this happens?
`multiprocessing.Queue` is for use with **one** `Process`, you are using `multiprocessing.Pool`, which uses multiple `Process`, you have to use 
`multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()`.

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Hi, thanks, this code snippet works for me on Python 3.5. By the way, how do you make the RuntimeError shown, I can't see any error even if running with the console. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mirage: Didn't show me too. I come across this Runtime Error in another project and using `mp.Manager()` is the solution I'm found.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

- you use apply_async, which returns immediately. so you should wait for the result somewhere
- under the hood, python will pickle the function to be executed to the child process. but self.process as a method is not pickle-able here (because of the self.pool attribute, see comment by ShadowRanger below).

---

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def subprocess():   # is a plain old (pickle-able) function
    for i in range(10):
        print("Running")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Subprocess Completed")
    return True

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)

    def start(self):
        result = self.pool.apply_async(subprocess)
        print("Subprocess has been started")
        result.get()    # wait for the end of subprocess
        self.pool.close()
        self.pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    test.start()
```

Comment: For the record, there is nothing wrong with pickling methods in general. But the default pickling will have to pickle the instance itself, along with all its attributes (which must themselves be picklable). Since the `Pool` is an attribute, and `Pool`s are not picklable, you can't pass along a method on this class's instances w/o overriding the pickling helper methods to exclude the `pool` attribute. But for cases where the instance is picklable, the methods are perfectly legal; `pool.apply_async('abc\r\n'.strip, ('a\n',))` is perfectly fine, even though you passed a method, not a function.