# why multiprocessing.Queue() doesn't work but Manger.Queue() works in case of passing queue object to multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

As mentioned in the SO questions:

[Can I pass queue object in multiprocessing pool starmap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57657490/can-i-pass-queue-object-in-multiprocessing-pool-starmap-method/57657598#57657598)

[Sharing a result queue among several processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908781/sharing-a-result-queue-among-several-processes)

when using Pool method of multiprocessing, multiprocessing.Queue() doesn't work and gives error when passing queue to the method which needs to be processed. But when using Manager.Queue(), it works fine. There is no explanation for why this works in any of the answers, so thought of asking a seperate question for this.

As explained above, other duplicate seeming questions provide the answer by using  manager.Queue. But none of them explains why this helps; I have asked this question so that there is an explanation of why this method works and multiprocessing.Queue() doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.5 multiprocessing pool and queue don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155553/python-3-5-multiprocessing-pool-and-queue-dont-work)